# Extracting a json out of the main body of page source

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the data off the webpage below, using Selenium in Python 3:

https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1285051/Live/England-Premier-League-2018-2019-West-Ham-Huddersfield

If this URL is viewed as the page source (for Chrome users: view-source: https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1285051/Live/England-Premier-League-2018-2019-West-Ham-Huddersfield), there are some JSONs within the text. My aim is to scrape the first, and quite substantial JSON, which sits in the 'var matchCentreData' bit. A snippet is featured below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var matchCentreData = {"playerIdNameDictionary":{"14244":"Pablo Zabaleta",
   "89998":"Manuel Lanzini","34693":"Marko Arnautovic","93026":"Felipe Anderson",
   "300359":"Issa Diop","122980"
```

I am able to scrape the entirety of the page source, however, I am struggling to extract only the JSON above. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all you need.

```
page_json = driver.execute_script("return JSON.stringify(matchCentreData)")
# Do what you want with the json.
```

Worked for me just now. And if you want both this specifically AND the page html, then do this step, along with your page source grabbing logic. No need to extract it specifically from the page source when you have this.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to do some string manipulation. Check out [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), i think it will return the entirety of the DOM, and you can do some string work to parse out your relevant data.

Edit: I see you're actually trying to extract just the json string from the entire DOM string. What substring/regex's have you tried?

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to have to go down the regex route - just seems a relatively long winded process when a json is just sitting there!